# ANTLR4 4.12.0 and Go target visitor

Tags: go, antlr4

I have the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    Jagle "jagle/jagle"

    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4"
)

type GeneratorVisitor struct {
    *Jagle.BaseJagleVisitor // Embed the base visitor to avoid writing unused methods
}

func NewGeneratorVisitor() *GeneratorVisitor {
    return &GeneratorVisitor{}
}

func (v *GeneratorVisitor) VisitProg(ctx *Jagle.ProgContext) interface{} {
    fmt.Println("Found ProgContext node")
    return v.VisitChildren(ctx)
}

func main() {
    input, _ := antlr.NewFileStream("test1.bas")
    lexer := Jagle.NewJagleLexer(input)
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)
    parser := Jagle.NewJagleParser(stream)
    parser.BuildParseTrees = true
    tree := parser.Prog()

    visitor := NewGeneratorVisitor()
    fmt.Println(visitor)
    visitor.Visit(tree)
}
```

When run I get the following:

```
&{<nil>}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x5d5fce]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    c:/Users/guru/src/jagle/jagle.go:33 +0x14e
exit status 2
```

I can't figure out why visitor is null. I've tried to follow and search for every possible docs about ANTLR4 and Go target.

Comment: Sounds like this needs a bug report in the [ANTLR4 repository](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues), for the Go target.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. There are several problems that should be addressed. While you could work around this, there are a lot of problems: [The code is just not implemented](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8dcc6526cfb154d688497f31cf1e0904801c6df2/runtime/Go/antlr/v4/tree.go#L72), so you'd need to write the Visit* functions in your visitor; `tree.Accept(visitor)` works at least to 1st node, `visitor.Visit(tree)` doesn't; [There's no example in the doc](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/go-target.md); Visitors are not tested in the unit tests for the runtime.

Comment: For steps describing a workaround, see [this comment under the Issues section](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2504#issuecomment-1299123230).